# How to count json into html span

Tags: javascript, html, json, discord

i try to count my members on discord into my website with a HTML Span.

I can't get it to work

Source code: https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/366996506563051520/embed.json

Comment: What exactly have you tried? `JSON.parse(your_json_here).members.length` will give you number of members.

Comment: "with a HTML Span" you can't count. You can count it in JavaScript and then display in an HTML span.

Answer (score 1):

Got a barebones script for you here mate.
Just insert it in the `<body>` of your page

```
<span id="discord-counter"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/366996506563051520/embed.json', true);

        request.onload = function() {
          if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            document.getElementById("discord-counter").innerHTML = data.members.length;

          } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

          }
        };

        request.onerror = function() {
          // There was a connection error of some sort
        };

        request.send();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display the count in the span?

```js
var JSON = {"channels": [{"position": 15, "id": "368447071637995520", "name": "Kanal 1 [Max 3]"}, {"position": 18, "id": "368447393114619912", "name": "Kanal 1 [Max 5]"}, {"position": 16, "id": "368447172338778112", "name": "Kanal 2 [Max 3]"}, {"position": 19, "id": "368447450513408020", "name": "Kanal 2 [Max 5]"}, {"position": 17, "id": "368447261539303446", "name": "Kanal 3 [Max 3]"}, {"position": 20, "id": "368447509414150144", "name": "Kanal 3 [Max 5]"}, {"position": 6, "id": "368446298522910721", "name": "Premium Kanal 1"}, {"position": 7, "id": "368446708306280448", "name": "Premium Kanal 2"}, {"position": 8, "id": "368446767471132685", "name": "Premium Kanal 3"}, {"position": 3, "id": "367002932807204864", "name": "\u2753 Trenger Hjelp"}, {"position": 4, "id": "367005226143842305", "name": "\u2754 Hjelpe rom 1"}, {"position": 5, "id": "367005348176855042", "name": "\u2754 Hjelpe rom 2"}, {"position": 12, "id": "367006728815902731", "name": "\ud83c\udfae Spill Kanal 1"}, {"position": 13, "id": "367006767684517889", "name": "\ud83c\udfae Spill Kanal 2"}, {"position": 14, "id": "367006802593841164", "name": "\ud83c\udfae Spill Kanal 3"}, {"position": 22, "id": "372107835389116417", "name": "\ud83c\udfb5 Music"}, {"position": 9, "id": "367002370388918292", "name": "\ud83d\udcde Kanal 1"}, {"position": 10, "id": "367002446146306050", "name": "\ud83d\udcde Kanal 2"}, {"position": 11, "id": "367002508268273685", "name": "\ud83d\udcde Kanal 3"}, {"position": 0, "id": "367007445660205057", "name": "\ud83d\udd10 Ledelsen"}, {"position": 1, "id": "367007363544383498", "name": "\ud83d\udd10 Staff 1"}, {"position": 2, "id": "367015859165593610", "name": "\ud83d\udd10 Staff 2"}], "instant_invite": "https://discordapp.com/invite/8ZPte4", "id": "366996506563051520", "members": [{"username": "Cp1987", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/241640752180887552/e6059ce87fc11dbf995c91e4036cd5e7.jpg", "avatar": "e6059ce87fc11dbf995c91e4036cd5e7", "discriminator": "2544", "id": "241640752180887552"}, {"username": "Cymares", "status": "dnd", "game": {"name": "Minecraft"}, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/106126923385577472/63d8cbac498b4f6cfeb1a4c08a835aaf.jpg", "avatar": "63d8cbac498b4f6cfeb1a4c08a835aaf", "discriminator": "4892", "id": "106126923385577472"}, {"username": "Defcon70", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png", "avatar": null, "discriminator": "2936", "id": "365492912626073612"}, {"username": "EOlai", "status": "online", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/310137542475513871/aaef1908f3531f7212a0b85b7824deb0.jpg", "avatar": "aaef1908f3531f7212a0b85b7824deb0", "discriminator": "1854", "id": "310137542475513871"}, {"username": "FredBoat\u266a\u266a", "status": "online", "bot": true, "game": {"name": "Say ;;help"}, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/184405311681986560/f20c8d9639cd674652254af0ffd3e9d2.jpg", "avatar": "f20c8d9639cd674652254af0ffd3e9d2", "discriminator": "7284", "id": "184405311681986560"}, {"username": "Hawz", "status": "idle", "nick": "Byggepus", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/173651756259999744/94a1928d2c5c0c4a5deee6a7dbd32a73.jpg", "avatar": "94a1928d2c5c0c4a5deee6a7dbd32a73", "discriminator": "8876", "id": "173651756259999744"}, {"username": "Johannern96", "status": "dnd", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/162105042369904640/f0a3428a57f1f5488e092fa677b6a20b.jpg", "avatar": "f0a3428a57f1f5488e092fa677b6a20b", "discriminator": "1603", "id": "162105042369904640"}, {"username": "Jonas (GuttaFraGjerdrum)", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/287902961143906305/5addd74e9bdaebd4a4121b38e3549232.jpg", "avatar": "5addd74e9bdaebd4a4121b38e3549232", "discriminator": "3369", "id": "287902961143906305"}, {"username": "Marty", "status": "online", "nick": "Marty9_", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/227493463556489216/60be07cee940f8f98abc79df424d0e1b.jpg", "avatar": "60be07cee940f8f98abc79df424d0e1b", "discriminator": "0960", "id": "227493463556489216"}, {"username": "MrAadde", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png", "avatar": null, "discriminator": "7015", "id": "305626866876678145"}, {"username": "Mrmax", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/293790449335009280/255a66982fe000966fc0051f249f28ea.jpg", "avatar": "255a66982fe000966fc0051f249f28ea", "discriminator": "6948", "id": "293790449335009280"}, {"username": "n0rthwindo", "status": "online", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/190825560878874626/aa10bc6d74e0dc2f62829a4a3eff2091.jpg", "avatar": "aa10bc6d74e0dc2f62829a4a3eff2091", "discriminator": "6116", "id": "190825560878874626"}, {"username": "OfficialAndy", "status": "online", "game": {"name": "NoahCraft.no"}, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/122778933065154564/921ce6330d8c7494d4dc18cc8099db0f.jpg", "avatar": "921ce6330d8c7494d4dc18cc8099db0f", "discriminator": "7219", "id": "122778933065154564"}, {"username": "Olapola", "status": "idle", "game": {"name": "Minecraft"}, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/191303467162271744/cac577e184788bec5ec24997af17c6b0.jpg", "avatar": "cac577e184788bec5ec24997af17c6b0", "discriminator": "1182", "id": "191303467162271744"}, {"username": "Rythm", "status": "online", "bot": true, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/235088799074484224/8917d25c11a6c155a81d54640c6fd35a.jpg", "avatar": "8917d25c11a6c155a81d54640c6fd35a", "discriminator": "3722", "id": "235088799074484224"}, {"username": "SoSanCo", "status": "idle", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png", "avatar": null, "discriminator": "8110", "id": "359025090022604801"}, {"username": "Taboovector", "status": "online", "game": {"name": "Ben and Ed - Blood Party"}, "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/182508242725765120/65b9a4d9a93df15fdd3076ab87cc2509.jpg", "avatar": "65b9a4d9a93df15fdd3076ab87cc2509", "discriminator": "4829", "id": "182508242725765120"}, {"username": "Valpepusen", "status": "online", "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/329901346511781888/28c3b87171526bd5c03f1450e6e04e4e.jpg", "avatar": "28c3b87171526bd5c03f1450e6e04e4e", "discriminator": "6886", "id": "329901346511781888"}], "name": "SkyLands"};

var membersSpan = document.getElementById('members');

membersSpan.innerHTML = JSON.members.length;
```

```html
<p><span id='members'></span> members.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code Hope It Will Help

```
string postURL = https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/366996506563051520/embed.json;

                var myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(postURL);
                myRequest.Method = "POST";
                myRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                myRequest.GetRequestStream();
                var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                var data = response.GetResponseStream();
                var streamRead = new StreamReader(data);
                var result = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                var count = result.Length;
```

//Now Put var count into span

Comment: i dont know what language that is (looks like broken C# to be honest), but it sure ain't javascript.

Comment: It is c# Code In Java script Put Your All string into a variable.and use Varname.members.Length to get Count of members