# Show Discord Server member count on a web page?

Tags: javascript, count, html, discord, member

How can I show the member count from my discord server on my website? Could it work with a Javascript?

I hope my English is understandable :'D

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total number of members in Discord using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454876/get-total-number-of-members-in-discord-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count json into html span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950885/how-to-count-json-into-html-span)

Comment: @Katamari the other one is `PHP`, while I've found a dupe with a `JS` example.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bot to count your current members. Then send the data to your database and show it on your website.